# Add a value to column

Tags: excel, vba, row, addition

I'm really new in Excel VBA programming and I have got a question.

I've got an Excel table that looks like this:

```
t   t1   t2 

1    4    5  

2    3    6

3    5    8
```

How can I skip the first row with the header `t,t1,t2` and then add the number **3** to the values in every row?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: read about `for next loops` `for each loops` `loops` in general `excel.range object`

Comment: and start your loop at the second row

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
        Sub test_loop()

            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                For i = 2 To lastRow
                    For j = 1 To lastCol
                        Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value + 3
                    Next j
                Next i

    End Sub
```